# Can the LibreOffice LightProof grammar library be used externally?

Tags: python, api, libreoffice

[LibreOffice 3.5 includes a grammar checker](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2012/02/libreoffice-35-released-introduces-new-grammar-tool.ars), called (or maybe based on) LightProof. From what I have read, LightProof seems to be a Python library that can be used to check for custom grammar rules. But I can not for the life of me find a project page for LightProof.

The closest I got was http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/lightproof/tree/, which seems to be the code for the LibreOffice extension, not LightProof itself.

So is LightProof actually a library that can be implemented in other applications, or is it just a code word for a LibreOffice feature?

Comment: Note that you might get a faster and more detailed answer using one of the [libre office mailing lists](http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/mailing-lists/).

Comment: No you can't use it. See http://libreoffice.hu/2011/12/08/grammar-checking-in-libreoffice/ for some details about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightProof has been superseded by LanguageTool, the source of which [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible yet, but: "we will be able to make a stand-alone version of Lightproof/Grammalecte as it won’t be necessary to use Hunspell anymore" - see Olivier R.'s post to the [LibreOffice mailing list](http://markmail.org/message/irggxv5r6xhwz4m7?q=languagetool%20-list%3anet.sourceforge.lists.languagetool-devel%20order%3adate-backward).